# kahlan - unit test not working - getting - Exception` Code(0) with message "Undefined variable `request`

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony4

I am new to kahlan unit test, I have installed it on Symfony. I am getting following error when try to run - vendor/bin/kahlan

Error:
/category/list
    x it shows category list
      an uncaught exception has been thrown in `C:\web\simple-symfony-api-v2\vendor\kahlan\kahlan\src\Scope.php` line 109

```
  message:`Exception` Code(0) with message "Undefined variable `request`."
```

Code:

```
namespace App\Spec\Controller;

describe('CategotyController', function() {
  describe('/category/list', function() {
    it('shows category list', function() {

      $request = $this - > request - > create('/category/list', 'GET');
      $response = $this - > kernel - > handle($request);

      var_dump($response);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After testing, debugging and some reading on google/documentation, I found I was missing - kahlan-config.php - this file need be added to the root of the Symfony project.

Code:

```
<?php // kahlan-config.php 

use App\Kernel;
use Kahlan\Filter\Filters;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

Filters::apply($this, 'bootstrap', function($next) {

    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $root = $this->suite()->root();
    $root->beforeAll(function () {
       $this->request = Request::createFromGlobals();
       $this->kernel  = new Kernel('test', false);
    });

    return $next();

});
```